# Scrapy: Can't override __init__function

Tags: python, scrapy

I have created a spider which inherits from CrawlSpider.

I need to use the `__init__` function but always getting this error:

code:

```
class mySpider(CrawlSpider):

 def __init__(self):
   super(mySpider, self).__init__()
     .....
```

this is the error I'm getting:
KeyError Spider not found: mySpider.

without the `__init__` function everything works

Comment: The semantics of `super` can be confusing sometimes. Try `CrawlSpider.__init__(self)`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to put it like this:

```
def __init__(self, *a, **kw):
    super(MySpider, self).__init__(*a, **kw)
    # your code here
```

Working example:

```
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "company"
    allowed_domains = ["site.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.site.com"]

    def __init__(self, *a, **kw):
        super(MySpider, self).__init__(*a, **kw)
        dispatcher.connect(self.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)
```

Here init was used to register scrapy signals in spider, I needed it in this example in spider instead of usually in pipeline

Comment: Still not good.

I did self.name = 'company'
I did: scrapy crawl company
same error

Comment: KeyError Spider not found: company
do I need to run it in different manner?

Comment: Is there a function I can override to do my pre scrape actions instead of init?

Comment: as I said:
self.name = 'company' 
then execute it via: scrapy crawl company

Comment: could you please explain what self._compile_rules() does?
baseSPider needs this function also?

Comment: @iblazevic: your advice is exactly wrong.  `super()` should be given the name of the current class, not the parent class, though that is a common misconception.

Comment: Excellent ans, Just can you tell how you found out ?